# Classes in class in c++

Tags: class, inner-classes

I have this block of code below, and I cant find out what that class ContractB : public: ContractA means? 
    #include

```
    using namespace std; 

    class ContractA
    {
        unsigned int ether = 0; 
    public: 
        ContractA(unsigned int e) :ether(e) {}
        auto sendEther() { return ether; }
    };

    class ContractB : public ContractA
    {
        unsigned int wei = 1;
    public:
        ContractB(unsigned int w) :wei(w) {}
        auto sendWei() { return wei; }
    };

    int main()
    {
        ContractB b(0); 
        cout << b.sendEther() << " " << b.sendWei();
        return 0; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It represents inheritance. 'public' is the access specifier that limits the most accessible level for the members inherited from the base class (ContractA).

You can read more about it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/).